# Is there a way to preserve HTML Formatting in LiveDocX?

Tags: php, zend-framework, frameworks, livedocx

I have a large amount of content stored in a database as XHTML. I need to be able to pull this formatted content into a simple LiveDocX template with the formatting (bold, italic, bulleted lists, etc) preserved.

Is this possible?
If so, can anybody post a working example or link to an article?
If not, are there other applications that I could look into?

The client needs to be able to export content in the .doc/.docx file format.

Thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 1):

According to the LiveDocX blog, adding html formatted text during a merge was supposed to be a feature of version 1.3 (currently, the production version is 1.2), but they decided to go ahead and merge the 1.3 branch and 1.2 together, effectively updating 1.2

This should mean that html formatted merge content is possible however there is absolutely no mention of this in the API documentation - http://www.livedocx.com/pub/documentation/api.aspx - or the blog - http://blog.livedocx.com/

Perhaps, as a work around, you could write a script that would make your stored content available as a webpage and then use a service such as websnapr.com to capture an image of that content and then insert the image into the document using LiveDocX.

As an aside, I'm looking for alternatives to LiveDocX also and will post a question on Stackoverflow.